# JFreeChart flip range axis orientation

Tags: range, orientation, jfreechart, axis, title

I'm creating a JFreeChart with 2 range axis, according to [this tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartDualAxisDemo.htm).

The result of the tutorial looks like this:
[image]

In this example, the "Secondary" range title reads from top to bottom, but I would like to rotate it 180 degrees and have it read from bottom to top, just like the primary range axis labeled "Value". How can I achieve this?

I looked at the `org.jfree.chart.axis` api but I didn't find anything relevant to the orientation of the axis titles.

Comment: Absent API support, you can override `Axis::drawLabel` to change the orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API Support to do this currently (JFreeChart 1.5.0), thanks to trashgod for pointing this out.

The only way to do this currently is to extend the NumberAxis class (which is used to instantiate the chart), and override the `drawLabel()` method.

To ensure the overridden `drawLabel()` method is implemented as properly as possible, I would reference the source code for Axis.java in `org.jfree.chart.axis`. The source code is easy to find online.

The default implementation of `drawLabel()` is so bulky however that I think I'm not going to try this. It simply isn't worth my time.